# PetaPoco \ NPoco - Partial Insert

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, insert, petapoco, micro-orm

Is there a way to partially insert an object using PetaPoco or NPoco?
For example, I have a table called Users:

```
UserId | UserName | UserMail | UserCreationDate
```

Each one of these columns are NON NULLABLE and have a default value when they are left empty.

In ASP.NET I have a User class, and I use the ORM to insert a new record with only the name:

```
Dim userData As New User()
userData.UserName = "Jimmy Hendrix"
db.Insert(userData)
```

I expect the database to look as follows:

```
UserId |   UserName    |   UserMail  | UserCreationDate
  12   | Jimmy Hendrix | (DB default)|  (DB default)
```

I want the insert command only insert the name, without inserting the other object properties with the object's default values.

Such as there is a partial update, I want a partial insert.
Is that possible in PetaPoco?

Is there another way to do it by myself without any ORM?

**Edit:**

Using SQL I can get the job done, but I need to use POCO objects, so I don't want to have to remember the database parameters. I want something like

```
user.UserName = "Michael"
user.Insert(user)
```

And it will insert only the UserName, ignoring the other variables. The SQL that I want to be generated in the background is:

```
"INSERT Users(UserName) VALUES(@UserName)"
(while the @UserName parameter holds the userData.FirstName value)
```

As you can see, it doesn't take in account the other variables in the class.
Today if I use the insert command, even if I give a value to a single property in the class, NPoco still tries to insert ALL the class variables into the db setting the variables I didn't want to set with the class's default values (which are different from the db default values)

Also, all of the properties are insertable/updateable, so there can't be any ResultColumn types in the class. I want to insert these values but only the ones I declare in that particular instance. All of the properties are available to update and insert but for each instance i insert only what i declare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a PartialUserForInsert class:

```
[TableName("Users")]
public class PartialUserForInsert
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This would force me to create a class for each insert update I do in the system. It would cause in thousands of classes like that. I don't know which fields I will be inserting each call and I wouldn't want to be forced to create several classes like that

Comment: I think that is your only option other than @CallMeKags's answer below.  I know a number db layers will first hydrate the model object with a select statement to ensure that the model state is current before performing an update.   Maybe you could use this approach?

Comment: Btw, your application sounds very complex if you have thousands of partial insert/update patterns.  Are there 1000+ tables in your system?

Comment: I have hundreds of tables in my project, but when I am working on the code and want to insert some data from the "Users" table, sometime I want to insert a partial data and let the DB defaults do the rest. The "Users" table has a LOT of columns, and I wouldn't want to create a separate class for each INSERT command I do. There will be hundreds of different classes with different  field combinations.

Comment: I accept this answer for being the most correct for the question I asked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your provided schema does not include a `FirstName` column.

Assuming the column is mapped to `UserName`, using the following should insert as expected.

```
dim sql = new Sql("INSERT Users(UserName) VALUES(@0)", userData.FirstName)
db.Execute(sql)
```

Comment: Using SQL I can get the job done, but I need to use POCO objects, so I don't want to have to remember the database parameters.

I want something like:
user.UserName = "Michael"
user.Insert(user)

And it will insert only the UserName, ignoring the other variables.
The sql you posted is what I want to happen in the background by PetaPoco.

Comment: Mark the properties which have default values with `ResultColumn` attribute. This will prevent any updates to this properties. You will however have to explicitly include these columns when retrieving the data.

Comment: But i don't want to set them as ResultColumn because all of the properties are insertable/updateable. I want to update these values but only the ones I declare in that particular instance. All of the properties are available to update and insert but for each instance i insert only what i declare

Comment: Hi, it's been a while. Can anyone help me with my problem? I'd be grateful if somebody helped me to solve this issue.